# Structuring a MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am trying to design my first NoSQL database, and as an example I am trying to grab content from Twitter. I have though some difficulties deciding how to structure the document.

If I am grabbing from several tags (e.g. #Programming #stackoverflow #nosql etc.) each day, how should I structure the documents so they doesn't grow too large and I still can do analytics based on all the tags?

I thought of creating documents like this:

```
/{day}/{hashtag}
```

This would get me the following:

```
/28052012/Programming

/28052012/StackOverflow 

/28052012/NoSql
```

But how would I then get the latest 5 Tweets from the combined hashtags?

Comment: But what are the performance implications if this is done across multiple documents?

Comment: Thanks, if you write your comment as answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`$or` operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or). It can use indexes and will allow you to perform efficient queries.